# Chocolat.js Lightbox jQuery not detecting element, returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chocolat.js

I'm trying to implement chocolat.js in a simple website. The problem I was having previously is that the thumbnail was just processing the anchor link directly--i.e. launching the image in a new window. It is supposed to launch it in a modal on screen and show some arrows and a close button. So I dug further, started implementing the additional code I thought I needed, but what seems to be happening, as I'm playing around in console, is that jQuery is not even picking up the element I'm tagging it with.

For example, in console, if I type `var instance = $('.chocolat-parent').Chocolat({loop:true,imageSize:'cover'}).data('chocolate');`
 it returns as `undefined`

Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.html:144)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
```

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="sl-gallery-cta flex-parent row align-center justify-space-around chocolat-parent" data-chocolat-title="set title">
                <a class="chocolat-image" href="./assets/stoneland-gallery-1.jpg" title="">
                    <img class="gallery-1" width="250" src="./assets/stoneland-gallery-1.jpg" />
                </a>
                <a class="chocolat-image" href="./assets/stoneland-gallery-2.jpg" title="">
                    <img class="gallery-2" width="250" src="./assets/stoneland-gallery-2.jpg" />
                </a>
                <a class="chocolat-image" href="./assets/stoneland-gallery-3.jpg" title="">
                    <img class="gallery-3" width="250" src="./assets/stoneland-gallery-3.jpg"/>
                </a>
                <a class="chocolat-image no-thumb" href="./assets/stoneland-gallery-4.jpg" title="">
                </a>
                <a class="chocolat-image no-thumb" href="./assets/stoneland-gallery-5.jpg" title="">
                </a>
                <div class="chocolat-wrapper">
                    <a class="api-next" href="#">Next</a>
                    <a class="api-prev" href="#">Prev</a>
                    <a class="api-close" href="#">Close</a>
                    <div id="container3" style="width: 80%; max-width:1000px; height: 600px; background: #E0E0E0; margin:auto;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var instance = $('.chocolat-parent').Chocolat({
        loop: true,
        fullscreen: true,
        imageSize: 'cover'
    }).data('chocolate');
    instance.api().open();
    window.setInterval(function(){
        instance.api().next();
    },2000);
    $('.api-close').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('close start');
        var def = instance.api().close()
        def.done(function(){
            console.log('close done');
        })
    })
    $('.api-prev').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('prev start');
        var def = instance.api().prev()
        def.done(function(){
            console.log('prev done');
        })
    })
    $('.api-next').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('next start');
        var def = instance.api().next()
        def.done(function(){
            console.log('next done');
        })
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var instance = $('.chocolat-parent').Chocolat({
    loop: true,
    fullscreen: true,
    imageSize: 'cover'
}).data('chocolate');
```

It seems you have a typo, it should be `chocolat` instead of `chocolate` on that last line.

```
}).data('chocolat');
```

Comment: Gotta love typos. Thanks for catching it!